# Regarding the reputation criteria for chatting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Today I had this incident. I was asking some more details from the OP regarding his/her question. Then I got a message stating not to extend discussion on comments rather use chat. But unfortunately the OP didn't have enough reputation points to chat. See, image below:

[image: chat issue]

Is there any solution already available for it? I don't unnecessarily want to up-vote OP's question to provide him/her some rep points just for a chat.

Can the reputation points criteria for a chat be lowered?

Comment: When the rep requirement is too low chat has a hard time dealing with spam/trolls

Comment: But in this chat there will be only two persons, me and OP. So if OP spams I can simply close the discussion. :)

Comment: Then they go into another chatroom and spam *it*.

Comment: Then this feature needs some changes. The OP shouldn't be allowed to do so. What about creating a temporary chat room? The user with high rep can simply decide when to close chat and then OP will be kicked or removed automatically.

Comment: That's quite a good idea. A sandbox for answer-related chatting _only_.

Comment: user3292475? It isn't hard to read it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat

Comment: @bjb568 Yes, it was a bit stupid idea of mine to hide the OP's display name in the screen shot. A clever/intelligent user can simply visit my profile and click on the activity tab and see that what question was I discussing with the OP. Did you use the same trick? :P

Comment: This reminds me of the perennial, "You posted a comment as an answer. Bad, bad, bad. You should have posted it as a comment. Of course, you don't have enough reputation to post comments, so what could you do. But the rules say you are now a bad boy." StackOverflow's rules definitely have some internal consistency problems.

Comment: @Kazark yes, one more from me related to posts which need to be fixed for code or error log identation only. I fix the identations but I can't submit my edit because I get a message that at least 6 new characters needs to be added, so I usually add `Thanks` to every edited post. But recently a high rep user asked me not to do so! I asked so what to do then? Till date I didn't receive any reply yet! Personally I think that fixing the code/error log is important as compared to fixing the English grammar mistakes. Because how can one provide a solution if the code is not understood correctly!

Answer (score 57):

I've wondered about a way to solve this myself because sometimes I want to help someone without making the post too messy. I may see that someone is close but missing some important concepts of the language/framework and to explain it in comments would get very messy. It would be nice if we could somehow allow this. Some thoughts...

- Would it be a problem if we allowed higher rep users to invite lower
  rep users to a private chat for these reasons? They still wouldn't be
  able to start a chat or join a room.
- Maybe attach a timer to the session or close it when the higher rep user leaves
- I'm not sure if we would want the rep to be higher or if 20 would work. If we are worried about too many lower rep users starting a chat and getting too far off-topic then possibly make the rep minimum for this feature higher (1-2k?)
- Gallery mode by default? If this is a higher rep user function then that person should have the choice if he doesn't want others potentially interrupting/giving "bad" advice. (I'm not sure how this works now; I will have to investigate)

So I'm not necessarily suggesting we lower the rep minimum for chat altogether but just for these instances where a higher rep user wants to give a little extra advice that is otherwise difficult and confusing in comments.

Would this be too difficult or cause issues I'm not thinking about?

**Related**- Allow the chat to start sooner in comments. I'm not sure what it is right now (seems like more than 10) but if you get 5 or so comments *only* between 2 people then typically moving to chat at that point has seemed more appropriate, from my experience.

Comment: Yes, you suggestions seems lucrative to me. I also thought of implementing some temporary chat room just for this purpose. Adding a time limit will certainly help.

Comment: I like these ideas, too - personally

Comment: +1 (but only because I can't do +10) for "Allow high rep users to invite low rep users to chat".  I'd be OK with "high rep" being higher than the threshold for being able to chat -- I'd suggest 10K but wouldn't be worried by some lower (2K?) or higher (15K?) threshold.

Comment: @jonathan Isn't 15k kinda… high?

Comment: 15K is high; somewhere between 2K and 10K is probably appropriate.  It could be a new level to give people an intermediate goal to aim for (7.5K or 4K)?  I've got a distorted view of reality; sorry about that.  It depends in part on whether the SO Team have a reason for not allowing such chats at the moment.  I know I've had the problem on a number of occasions -- I might even have asked about it, or found the equivalent question on MSE (MSO as was, when it was MSO) and upvoted that.

Comment: Users with 1K can create a Gallery chat room, so maybe that threshold would be enough

Comment: I have run into this so many times, +100 if I could. 1K seems reasonable, there are enough mid-rep users that would utilize this it seems a shame to restrict them.

Comment: I'd say 500 rep.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily be against 500 but that is lower than what I would like to see. Might be better to start out higher and see how it goes? Then have the possibility to lower if it was working out well?

Comment: Meh, you 20kers and you're fake throne... :P

Comment: Is there any need to even have a rep requirement for creating a private chat room? I'm not sure I care if low-rep users spam themselves.

Comment: @Gabe The first thing that comes to mind is a waste of resources. We don't want to build a playground for them to spam and mess around. Now, I don't have any idea what the costs would be but I think having a higher rep user that knows the site better, and possibly their field, would help to control the chat and lead the users to better programming habits and SO habits.

Comment: There is a moderation cost to creating chat rooms. They may not be *actively* monitored, but stuff happens that requires attention. With alarming frequency. @gabe

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't use chat rooms so I'm not familiar with the moderation requirements, but I'd have to imagine that a private chat room would require less moderation than the equivalent comment threads.