# Chat with a new user

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, chat

If you take a look into [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799561/tomcat-6-0-35-installation-on-mac-os-x-10-9/23799813?noredirect=1#comment36649049_23799813), the OP is confused about a lot of things and need more guidance and help on a number of small things.

The original question was somewhat answered to some extent but OP is still confused about a lot of other things and keeps asking things in the comments.

I am more than happy to help but its in the Law of stackoverflow that extended discussions on comments are discouraged and that discussion like these need to be moved over to the chat room. But in this case the OP is a new user and I can't invite him over to the chat as he doesn't have enough reputation. I still tried to help as much as I could over the comments but its not enough to satisfy the OP at the moment ( so it seems )

So any idea as to how to proceed in this case ? Shall I ask OP to open up a new question post for each of his/her question?

Comment: [Related to the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255825/regarding-the-reputation-criteria-for-chatting) though if it is a completely separate question then it should be formulated and posted as such to help future users.

Comment: When I'm in this situation, I usually invite the OP for an email chat. I publicly advertise my email address that I have on my personal domain for this exact reason (don't use my main email address for this as to make it easy to sever the account if it's spammed, which surprisingly it isn't).

Answer (score 11):

These are [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) that change in premise or scope as answers arrive, and the best thing to do is get out of them. Encourage the OP to go try and figure it out, as it's beyond the scope of what they've asked - and come back *if* they're not able to figure it out. You can leave some general guidance for them to get started, but leave it *on your way out*.

It's not fair for experienced users of the site to get sucked into these scenarios where they almost feel obligated to hold someone's hand through an entire project, and it's not fair to instill the expectation that we do this in new users - because we don't, for the most part.

Just keep the focus on whatever question you originally answered, and exit if it looks like you're about to get caught up in a web of 'scope creep'. Taking it to chat just sort of legitimizes this practice, and that's something we'd like to avoid (and part of the reason why we have the rather low, but very effective bar in place).

There are always exceptions, but it's just *silly* easy to get enough rep to chat. The only time circumventing the limit seems like a good idea is when you have a 'speaker' that wants to interact with a room, and for whatever reason can't or doesn't wish to answer questions in order to be able to do so, and that's quite rare to begin with.

Now, if they've got someone willing to help them, which is an awful lot of help - surely they can give us something too (and in doing so demonstrate that they have the capacity to actually benefit from said help)? In *most* cases, the most helpful thing you can do is exit with some advice on what's next, and let them toil about with it.

Comment: FWIW, I'd argue that these chameleon questions are direct, unintended consequence of S.O. rules. We all know that noobs often don't know how to ask the right question yet, and thus every answer results in them getting closer to asking the right question. Because we cannot initiate a chat and quickly dispense with all of this silliness, they're forced to ask them in comments and/or constantly revise the original question. I don't think the solution is vague counsel that you leave "on your way out", but rather give us the tools to help them (e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255828/1271826).

Comment: "It's not fair for experienced users of the site to get sucked into these scenarios..." 1. No one is forcing users to do anything.  It's their choice, and I don't think SO should choose for them. 2. While the OP's referenced question might not be specific, other questions people might want to chat about might be. 3. I don't see what the difference is between getting sucked into comment replies vs. sucked into a chat.  At least a chat is likely to waste less time.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to encourage OP to narrow down the problem. They should ask one question and then formulate the second question after they hit the next road-block.

Try to avoid solving too many things on comments, I have read that some people get sucked into that and end up solving questions for days just on comments.

For sure the more OP has to think about the problem the more they have to try by themselves and the better questions they will post.

Comment: You might point people to this post about [Help Vampires](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: 'End up solving questions for days on comments' yes I have also seen that happen a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the person above. I am VERY new at this programming stuff but find some very helpful and nice people on here who have given me a world of help. But, as has been mentioned, sometimes one question leads to another, then another and so on. If there was a way to communicate outside of SO, it would unclutter the board and maybe be able to help more.

Comment: While I agree in principle, I think there's an issue with allowing new users to participate in chat: it's too easy for people to create puppet accounts and spam chat rooms. Also, it becomes an issue of a single person trying to help being bombarded with questions from a new programmer. Being new is not a bad thing, but learning how to use the site is important, and separate questions should be asked as separate questions. Really, it only takes 20 rep to participate in chat. It's one of the first privileges you earn and it's not difficult: just 2 answer upvotes, 4 question upvotes, or 10 edits.

Comment: @AstroCB I wish we could invite a user to join us in _to that particular chat_ (as contemplated here in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255825/regarding-the-reputation-criteria-for-chatting). I understand the risk of granting user with no rep to chat freely everywhere, but there's got to be better solution. This current approach only encourages noob to ask a whole bunch of separate stupid questions (or repeatedly revise/edit question so it's constantly changing) that could have been dispensed with 5 minutes of chat.