# How to deal with a slowly learning user?

Tags: discussion, new-users, homework

So I met a certain user who posted their [homework problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094007/using-two-english-words-and-seeing-how-many-times-they-can-cross) on SO. They put some effort into answering their questions IMHO and are slowly getting there.

They got here already

```
public class Assg2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String w1 = args[1];
        String w2 = args[2];
        int numberOfCrosses = 0;
        for(i=0; i < w1.length(); i++) {
            for(j=0; j < w2.length(); j++) {
                if(w1.charAt(pos1) == w2.charAt(pos2)) {
                    numberOfCrosses++ System.out.print(w1, w2) 
                } 

                if(numberOfCrosses == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Words do not cross")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And as some of you may notice, this code will work properly, it just needs its compile errors fixed. Now this user has no idea how to fix this compile errors, so they just posted one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096394/writing-a-program-that-takes-two-words-and-finds-as-many-ways-the-two-words-can) regarding one of the compile errors. Now once this issue gets fixed, another issue will appear.

I predict that they will create another question for this issue and/or disscuss it in the comments in their two posts. **This is not good for the Q&A format of SO**. I am unable to invite the user to a chatroom because of their low reputation so I am lost at how to deal with this.

As for the code above, I actually went and fixed all the compile errors and ran it, confirming that it might be what they want, i.e. I have the answer to their homework but of course I don't want to spoonfeed it to them.

As the saying goes, *Give a man a fish, he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will eat for a lifetime*.

How do I deal with this? I want to help as I was once a beginner too. Or should I just leave them alone and get on with my life?

Comment: Maybe high rep users should be allowed to invite lower rep users to chat.

Comment: @Bob I'm thinking along those lines too, however, the [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat) for that did not seem to be closed or [status-completed] so I'm lost

Comment: This is how you get homework done. First, copy someone else's incomplete work as early as you can, then continually post it to SO until your slaves have done all your work for you.  You hardly need to do any work at all, you need next-to-no skill or knowledge but will still get a good grade.   Dump this vampire now.

Comment: Well I recognize that they're a vampire and that I could dump them right now. However, I saw a small ray of hope that I could save them and maybe impart some teachings. Is this ray of hope a false ray of hope? :(

Comment: As always, it's a thin line. A casual search on fragments of the assignment and OP's own attempt yielded nothing suspicious – the true help vampire is not above copying someone else's honest attempt and presenting it as his own. So I can see where your glimmer comes from: at least OP appears to have tried *something*.

Comment: True enough, but that changes nothing about the fact that before you can do homework, you need to study what the homework is about. I see too many people on SO who ask questions without having done any kind of study at all, they're just trying stuff and hoping for the best. All you can do is downvote, anything else is enough of a reward that they'll keep avoiding doing the one thing that will get them anywhere - personal effort.

Comment: i have seen in many cases where even though the OP hasn't done anything some one might have answered the question completely despite many downvotes on the Question. At times its annoying to see questions being answered that manner when there are other questions which has enough details and effort from the OP being unanswered. I have felt the same many times.  :(

Comment: Give a teacher a chance to teach the man and everybody can buy his fish.

Comment: @Bob I, for one, would not want such a feature that is designed to waste the time of high-rep users with one-on-ones with vampires.

Comment: I prefer: **Give a man a fish, he will eat for a day. Give a man a fishing rod and he'll swap it for a fish.**

Comment: Give a teacher a chance to teach the man and hundreds of deadbeats will turn up, demanding free fishing lessons.  Sod 'em, let 'em starve.

Comment: In this case I'd probably just post a comment that "You're missing a couple of semi-colons from your code.", pointing them in the right direction but still leaving them lots to do. And it's usually at this point someone posts the full corrected code...but that's a different story. I'm happy to help newbies but I wouldn't spend 10 seconds on something as obvious as this.

Comment: The actual saying is: **Give a man a fire, keep him warm for a day. Set a man on fire, keep him warm for the rest of his life.**

Comment: @biziclop Would it be poor SO etitique to downvote an answer provides the full correct code to homework problem even if it's correct, when OP was so close to solving it on their own?  I'm always tempted to do it, but figure it's wrong to downvote something that's correct.

Comment: The actual actual saying is: **Give a man a match, he will come back for a matchbox. Give a man a fire, he will burn down the village.**

Comment: **Give a man a fish, and he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish, and he will sit in a boat and drink beer for a day**

Comment: It is funny how the comments went from **"Yes, lets discuss the point"** to **"Set a fish on fire, and a teacher will swap for a village"** ..... Anyhow... on my personnal experience, its best to guide him on the importance of marks (such as `;`), and a google link on what the commands mean, rather than fix the problem and post it..... Programmers must understand from the eletricity crossing the stone, to the complexity of !O operations. since its a lot to learn in a small lifespan, then point the direction, but NEVER show the result

Comment: Remember those that you spoon feed answers will one day be your peers and you will be doing their work for them for free as well as your own while they get paid for it and credit for the work as well. They will eventually be your manager or team lead most likely because they have time to play the socio-political games and advance because everyone else is doing their work for them and they are getting credit for it. **Do not be an enabler!**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: **Give a man a keyboard, and he will be your manager by day.** (No mention of women in the parables...)

Comment: [It is getting fishy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime).

Comment: Once I realize an asker is going to try to keep coming at me with question after follow-up question until I should write their instructor and ask for part of his or her paycheck, or once I see someone reputable in the community request that the asker edit the question for clarity, and the asker fails to do so, I cease all communication on that question immediately.  It's like helping a child with a school project.  The adult, knowing more, could do the whole thing.  But the learner should at least put in a token effort.

Comment: I'd like to point out that I did not notice the user posted the same question already. Disregard what I said previously.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the insight. And of course it's alright to throw in the jokes about that famous saying. Meta is like the *after office bar* as the Main Site is like the *office* itself, so AFAIK jokes are welcome here.

Comment: As far as the discussion goes, I guess it comes down to experience in dealing with people. I for one does not deal with people that much and it was my first time seeing a new user  get somewhere so I felt like *oh, they got here! then maybe all they need is a little more push*. Of course if they really got there by themselves and was able to solve their problems, then good for them. Until then we will just keep closing their questions.

Comment: I think the important thing is maintaining the quality of the site. If the only way to help the person is outside of the guidelines of the sight, ie, by answer questions that should be closed rather than answered, then it may be a shame, but it is not our place or responsibility to provide that help.

Comment: @JNYRanger It doesn't matter if an answer is correct. What matters is whether it's useful or not. If I think an answer to a terrible question is only useful to the help vampire (or one of their classmates looking for answers for the same homework question), I would downvote the answer as **not useful** (to the collective site users). However, if I think the answer is general enough that it *may* help other users, I'll leave it be. In some cases, I'll upvote it, if I think it benefits the site as a whole.

Comment: There was a time jokes be welcome in the mainsite, take for granted there will be a time were jokes are banned in meta. I guess for good. Aren't they more suited to chatroom-like?

Comment: I think the irony of this thread is that the the user in question may get a gold badge awarded for being a question with high traffic!

Comment: **Give a man a fish, and he will eat for a day. Give a man a fishing rod, and he will whip you with it until you give him a fish.**

Comment: Only this is true: **Give Stack Overflow a canonical compiler error fix answer one day and users can close compiler error questions as duplicate for lifetime.** I'd really like to see such answers, per IDE (VS, Eclipse, ...) and per language (C++, C#, Java, ...).

Comment: @MartinJames: You're alive!

Comment: @Bob: So, the 'ideally' suggestion in [Stack Overflow should not invite you to move a discussion to chat…](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275771/stack-overflow-should-not-invite-you-to-move-a-discussion-to-chat-when-one-of-th) and its relatives might be helpful.

Comment: Might be related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255866/chat-with-a-new-user

Comment: I'm getting hungry, hope we have something delicious for dinner tonight, fish maybe?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Said user also posted this question before the one referenced:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096394/writing-a-program-that-takes-two-words-and-finds-as-many-ways-the-two-words-can

Look familiar?

Both these questions are nothing more than "do my homework for me because I can't figure out how". The "effort" you see being "put in" is probably code that they were helped to write in their classroom/lab, and whoever was helping them obviously didn't want to give the full answer, so this user turned to Stack Overflow.

Conclusion: obvious help vampire. Assisting this person is not adding quality content to Stack Overflow, and it's not helping them in the long run because they're either unable or unwilling to learn the absolute basics of programming. If we help them, maybe they'll flunk out of their class later - but they'll still flunk out. Rather they fail fast and stop wasting everyone's time, or pull up their socks and put in the effort of their own accord.

Comment: lets not ignore the vultures in that thread either. Vampires are useful critters, they make the hit & runners trip over themselves.

Comment: So you mean that the effort I saw is not really their effort per se? Ok I understand, and I will be more careful next time.

Comment: @Keale I'm not saying that *is* the case - I don't have enough evidence to prove or disprove it, one way or another - but based on the fact that the code was un-compilable and the user couldn't figure out how to fix the relatively simple errors... well, let's just say I've seen this before.

Comment: Rather than vampire or vulture, we should be calling this person an **Albatross**, because people are throwing them a LOT of fish! Perhaps we should not try to teach pigs to sing.

Comment: Teach a pig to sing and you have a serenade; give a pig a singe and you have a barbeque.

Comment: @philipxy There's a lot of animal metaphors in this question, so I can only assume that Meta is hungry.

Answer (score 16):

I think that in this situation you answer the first question if appropriate, but then cut it off if it seems to lead nowhere. I was surprised that a user could come up with a correct, two-dimensional algorithm for the problem, yet not know how to fix compile errors for missing semicolons? This would be my tipoff that something was going on behind the scenes.

I currently teach adults programming, and long ago in college (pre-internet) I worked as a Teaching Assistant for an introductory course in programming for non-majors. In that case, I learned to give only a few appropriate hints and not spoonfeeding. Sometimes it went back and forth. But I was sitting in the room with them. **In this situation, such coaching is impossible and inappropriate.** Sorry to say, but that's life.

The Internet is largely a repository of content, but where humans sit waiting to answer questions, we can have misuse by askers and naivete in answerers. In old times, a Librarian would point you to proper books, not do your work for you. This is basically the same. "*There is nothing new under the Sun.*" (Ecclesiastes)

Comment: You made my day by dropping the word "coach". I've been looking for that word for years when trying to answer for myself why "teaching" doesn't work in forums/Q&A sites, as it obviously does but fails miserably in specific until now unidentified (by me) moments. Fully agreed, coaching is the thing that won't work, it requires realtime feedback.

Comment: There is no substitute for the Apprentice - Journeyman - Master model. That is why it existed for so long. University and self-teaching are not always as good. Programming is now sufficiently complex that one cannot learn everything needed for an entry-level job by schooling. Internships, or more, are necessary now. It is like the medical field. For smaller issues, coaching is the method, like learning presentation or leadership skills.

Comment: Perhaps rather than opening up a feature for teams, SO should open a feature for forming study groups :)

Answer (score 11):

I think the most decent way to deal with such situations is to **help within the rules**.

When I spot such questions, I often do a couple of things:

1. First of all I'd check whether the question should be closed in the first place (homework questions are often considered "too broad").
2. If they put some effort (at least on how to ask a proper question) I'd check if the question can be considered *researched, clear and useful*. Otherwise, a down-vote is necessary.
3. Finally I'd try to help as much as I can without spoon-feeding by giving some tips mostly as comments (IMO by answering poorly written questions we are actually promoting garbage on the site).

Answer (score 10):

In short:

## Don't answer the first question.

And don't have the help vampire suck anyone else's blood, either.  Cast a close vote or flag the question.  But clarify why.

Firstly, questions should be focused on a single error or aspect of the code.  Otherwise, they are classifiable as "too broad" or off-topic for multiple reasons:

- Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

In other words, the OP must be specifically discussing *one* issue rather than posting code with many issues that he doesn't discuss.

Or even:

- This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced...This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem

If the OP can't post the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem, the combination of code is unique to his situation and the combination of problems in the code is not reproducible.

Thus, questions about entire homework problems belong to several categories of unsuitability.  Following Stack Overflow's policies should address the issue of the help vampire.

Yes, I have faith that help vampires can grow into good programmers and solid community members.  The OP is treated of vampirism and can be helped once he:

1. Breaks the code into individual problems, separating out the lines associated with each problem;
2. Articulates, in the post, multiple creative attempts to solve the problem;
3. The question is not a duplicate of another.

Comment: "I have faith that help vampires can grow into good programmers and solid community members" Unfortunately there will always be people who Just Don't Get It and there is nothing you can say or do to make them Get It. Attempting to assist people in that situation is fruitless because all you're actually achieving is the prolonging of their agony. I know this because I've been one of the Just Don't Get Its (in algebra) and eventually figured out that I should concentrate on what I understand and am good at (programming) versus trying to push a large boulder up a steep hill.

Comment: @IanKemp I remember when I first came across functional programming I didn't get it, and was stuck doing an assignment.  However after a while everything just clicked, and I spent a productive few hours coming up with a working solution.  So you can go from one state to the other.   However it does have to come from within, so there is little you can do to help someone.

Comment: @IanKemp we don't know for sure, and I would give this OP the benefit of the doubt.  It's possible OP is lazy.  If the OP were really a Just Don't Get It person that won't ever be able to post good questions, or won't ever be able to overcome the laziness, this obstacle would be insurmountable and OP would need to just give up anyway.

Comment: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Answer (score -6):

I basically think you should just answer what he asks you. I base this on 2 things:

1. When I was 13 and started to do some programming, I need help
   over those issues too. Learning all that is a process, and every
   time you get an answer you learn something new.
2. Some people just
       don't want the bigger help. In college there were people who didn't
       want me to help them by explaining, but rather just copy my answer.
       I did it in school too, I just wasn't interested in some subjects
       but still wanted to pass the exam. So letting me copy was a bigger
       help, in the short run as well as in the long run, because it helped
       me get better grades and get into college.

So I think the best thing to do in this situation is to help him if you have time, and will, or just ignore his questions if you don't. And for the people who are saying that it is "not helping him in the long run", I don't exactly understand that phrase. How do you know what he needs in the long run? Maybe hes not even studying programming, but this could rather be some bonus class he is taking. And you don't know if your help will help him in the long run - maybe passing this exam gets him motivated to learn more about programming. So if you don't have time or don't want to help, just don't. But please, don't try to find a "moral excuse" for not helping someone.

Don't think that you should impose your way of thinking to others. Not everyone is the same. So either help or don't, just don't make a huge moral discussion about long run. Let the guy live his life how he wants to.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. First and foremost, **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for **professional and enthusiast programmers**. We expect long term effects of the things we teach and learn here.

Comment: Of course I understand that, and I think your question was very good, and I agree that you should be given an option to chat with a person like that. My comment was more for the people who talk about "help vampire" and "Do not help him" kinds of things.

Comment: how you can help him is give him suggestions about what to focus on.  e.g., to break up the question and clarify the errors, as well as what he tried to do to solve the errors.  There are a couple reasons.  First, the act of writing a Stack Overflow question can help him find the answer, either by thinking about the answer himself or by following the suggested links to similar questions.  Second, better questions are more useful contributions and are more likely to get better answers.

Comment: Re: "But please, don't try to find a 'moral excuse' for not helping someone": Our reason for helping is that it aligns with our values. In cases where helping does *not* align with our values, we shouldn't help. This is not an "excuse", because we don't have any obligation to help, and therefore do not need any excuses to not help.

Comment: Also, I would like to add: Another of Stack Overflow's aim is to be a repository of good questions and answers that can be usable to anybody in the long run. Even if they do not need help in the long run, we expect their posts to help other people in the long run. Folks around here downvote and/or vote to close questions/answers that does not align with this aim.

Comment: And so he passes his exam, starts working at Boeing, and the Boeing drops out of the air...

Comment: In college I was a Teaching Assistant for an introductory programming course for non-computer majors. My answer would be: go to the TA with your questions. It is probably faster, easier and you will get better help in person. If the TA is in the Computer Lab, as I was, then you can try out the suggestions immediately and come back with more questions. *Computer Lab?* I guess I see why students don't do this anymore... Too bad. Convenience is not always an improvement. Sometimes we learn better around others.