# Is there a badge for the longest conversation in the comments?

Tags: discussion

Because I can not think of another reason for having such long conversations between just 2 people (well mostly) [86 comments and counting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39315028/1778421)

I do admire [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)'s patience though - maybe this deserves a separate badge?

But jokes aside my real question is - how would one determine if a long conversation deserves a moderator flag? Is there an official policy?

Comment: Not sure if deliberately trying to attract some kind of attention to a post or just meh. If you notice a long thread, cast a moderator flag for a diamond to move or nuke it.

Comment: is this a legit request? In any case, Badges are to ENCOURAGE behaviors... I don't think we want to encourage longer comment threads

Comment: There should have already been an auto flag raised for a long discussion- I don't know if the comments have to all be in a short time or not. Either way, with how long the discussion has gone on, a mod flag on the post that the comments are getting out of hand wouldn't be out of place. Meta isn't the best way to handle this situation, if that's what you wanted to do. If that's _not_ what you wanted to do, you may wish to make it clearer that you aren't trying to jokingly point this issue out.

Comment: is there some official guideline for the acceptable length of conversation?

Comment: Ah, I see, it's the "Shog is gonna kill you" badge. As for acceptable length, the more concise and efficient you get, the better.

Comment: When the system prompts the commenters to take the discussion to chat is generally when people should cut off discussions, or take them to chat if they wish to continue. Since comments are _supposed_ to be for clarification, they really shouldn't get so out of hand. But sometimes it does happen. I would have expected a mod to step in already, but either 1) the rate of the comments matters for the auto flag, and this conversation was spread out enough not to trigger it, 2) a mod hasn't gotten to that auto flag yet, or 3) the mod sees it all as relevant clarification.

Comment: 86 comments of *relevant clarification*? I highly doubt it

Comment: @AlexP I'd be surprised as well. In any case, the "proper length" is... well.... as many moderation guidelines, just how you feel. If you read it and go "THAT'S WAY TOO LONG", then yes, flag. Everyone's threshold is different, and there is no specific guideline

Comment: @Kendra: There *was* an automatic flag. It was automatically dismissed at the end of a 24-hour period in which no one said anything, before the conversation picked right back up. Guessing it went unnoticed prior to that.

Comment: as for *trying to attract some kind of attention to a post* - I do not care about this specific post but I would not mind some attention to the fact that the regular self-moderation tools do not work as effectively for the low traffic tags. even automated measures do not work because the expected timings are off

Comment: @BoltClock Hmm, never would have guessed that one. Thanks for the clarification on that!

Comment: @BoltClock Am I smelling a bug report?

Comment: @Braiam: The system does automatically invalidate a too-many-comments flag after a 24-hour period of no activity. I'm sure the current behavior could be improved in many ways - some of which I've suggested to the devs in private and they're taking into consideration.

Comment: related: [Chat with a new user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262088/839601)

Comment: You should: 1) Edit the relevant information into their respective posts, clarifying, organizing, and compressing wile doing so. Then flag the comment thread for deletion by flagging the first obsolete comment with a custom flag explaining that the relevant information has been added to the posts.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, that is a lot of back and forth between two users. In general it is not a good idea to create an 86 comment thread between two users on a question.

I know this question is about badges, but in no way shape or form should there be a badge encouraging this behavior.

In my opinion this case is an edge case, and should be an exception. All of the comments contain constructive material and are well-intentioned.

These exact comments should not be removed, but this type of extended discussion really should be in chat as the system will suggest. Chat is much more suited for this. Perhaps the comment thread could be migrated there.

Comment: this was not about badges. I just forgot that humor rarely helps one's cause here on meta

Comment: I also disagree with your assessment of *constructiveness* of the whole thread. From where I am at it looks like a lot of hand-handling and spoon-feeding from one side and just "gimme the codez" demands from the other. I do agree that the constructive part is worth saving

Comment: It is fine if you disagree, but I just do not see it the same way. To me it looks like two users who are having a legitimate conversation about the content of the post, with citation and code to back it up on both sides. Sure, there is a very slight amount of "do this" versus "why do it", but compared to what would be expected in 86 comments, it is all rather topical. That said, we still have 83 comments left to go.

Comment: in that thread I counted at least 8 demands to post an answer with a **working** code and a detailed explanation. The separate explanations of specific parts were quickly dismissed as "non-working". The OP just expected someone to post some code which he would be able to copy-n-paste into his project without any changes.

Comment: The thread is confusing because it devolves into an argument about the OP's self-answer but the comments were posted to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, badges are meant to reward desirable behavior. We don't want to reward or encourage this type of behavior. If you need to have a conversation, do it in chat, not the comments.

As for moderator flags, ALL comment flags are handled by mods unless enough flags accumulate or the comment contains "bad language" (the list includes many vulgarities and several commonly abused phrases).

As for cleaning up these long threads, it depends on what's in the comments.

- If it's the author's comment and it contains important info, consider adding it to the post and flagging as "no longer needed".
- If the comment contains criticism that has already been addressed via edits, flag as "no longer needed". (Make sure you get the corresponding "fixed it" comment, if there is one.)
- If the comment could have been expressed by voting (for example, it says "I agree" and nothing else), flag it.
- If there are multiple comments that all say the same thing, then see about flagging the duplicates. It might help to indicate that the information is already contained within another comment (and link to it).
- Of course, be sure to flag any rude comments, too.