# Room owners should be allowed to accept <20 rep users to talk in a room

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, chat

I'm a fairly heavy chat user - and I think for new users sometimes it's best to direct them to a room related to their question, whereby details can be thrashed out (avoiding a long stream of comments). Thereby, getting a question back into shape and answerable - possibly even answered and posted back to the main site.

I understand *why* the restriction exists, but I don't see why it shouldn't be able to be "over-ruled" by the ROs - upvoting a question just because it's enough to put them to the threshold to "talk" to them is not the way we need to be doing this.

**I propose that when a Room Owner grants write-access it's accepted for users < 20 rep**

The access can easily be revoked later if it turns out a nuisance, but from my experience that's generally not from < 20 rep users.

Comment: +1 for this, I've never understood that limit anyway

Comment: The limit makes sense so new users don't dump all their questions into chat "because it's easier". Also, imagine question-banned users with 1 rep. Do you really want them to chat? But besides that, I like your proposal. Room owners should be able to override the rep minimum.

Comment: Ok, I understand it better now, especially the question banned part. That convinced me.

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but [Invite low rep users to participate in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291) and [Regarding the reputation criteria for chatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255828) (that answer similarly requests to allow inviting low-rep users to chat)

Comment: @ThiefMaster I think a lot of "bad"/"ambiguous" can be sorted by the chat system... sort it out, get it done by the community... I don't like the restriction they can't come to the room to talk about it just because they haven't earned enough "rep". I don't want some silly prankster coming into the room to play jokes or be  a vampire, nor do I wish to miss the opportunity that we have a great team that helps - that's just me.

Comment: Chat as a replacement for long comment streams with a user who need hand holding because of a bad question? -1

Comment: @bjb568: If high-rep users want to take a noisy conversation off the main site to help someone regardless of their reputation, I say more power to them.

Comment: I say they should do something more productive.

Comment: @bjb568 what's more productive than reducing noise and helping someone learn the ropes as it were? The room I'm frequently in is more than willing to do so if needs be, it's just we *can't*... Be it on a rooms' head if they wish to, but it's a *choice* which ROs don't have at the moment... I'm not proposing that the entire chat system changes.

Comment: @Jon What's more productive? Reducing noise by reviewing. The system can then ban appropriately! You can't hold people's hands. That isn't what the site is for (professional or enthusiast programmer Q&A). It doesn't scale.

Comment: @bjb568 It's up to each individual to choose how he or she spends their time. If I choose to improve the resource we know as StackOverflow by editing or commenting on a question, then that's my choice. If I choose to engage with an individual who is asking a question with the goal of helping them to improve that question, then everybody wins. Perhaps it is you who "should do something more productive" by encouraging people to direct their energies where they will have a positive effect instead of attempting to tell other people what they can or cannot do?

Comment: @bjb568 It's more productive to question ban someone and have them make new users to ask questions then to have someone who is willing to help them so that they ask good questions? For me at least it seems better to work towards helping someone post a good question on the site then ignoring a poster till the system bans them.

Comment: @ClickRick Helping people to improve their questions, fair enough, but if we're directly helping them solve the issue they're having (in response to a bad question), this is actually pretty harmful to the site, as it provides positive reinforcement to their bad question. In my experience, any extended discussion usually tends to the latter rather than the prior.

Comment: @Dukeling Re helping them to solve the issue, I agree, but that's something I'm quite happy to knock back if they try it. I'm far more interested in helping others to improve their questions, as that will have the effect of making the site as a whole easier to search for good answers.

Comment: The real problem, in my view, is that when I'm trying to have an extended conversation with a questioner, SO offers to move the discussion into chat _even though the questioner is not allowed into chat_ because his rep is too low. (I think I'm right in my recollection that this is what happens.) It is right to offer me this option only if the option is _possible_.

Comment: @ClickRick "It's up to each individual to choose how he or she spends their time." No, you can't do whatever you want. There are rules put in place for good reasons. There is a meta discussion (here) on what the rules should be. Hand holding is harmful, as dukeling said.

Comment: @bjb568 "Doing whatever you want" is not at all what ClickRick is saying and you (should) know it. Just because you can't fathom a way to productively help a user in chat doesn't mean it's not possible. It's a lot easier for someone to improve when they're talking to a human and receiving feedback in a format they understand than it is to see your questions downvoted and closed and try to guess at why.

Comment: @Tyler "Just because you can't fathom a way to productively help a user in chat doesn't mean it's not possible." We're talking about averages here. It's generally unproductive and sometimes destructive to hand-hold people in chat. Therefore the behavior should be discouraged. And it is.

Comment: @bjb568 It's not against the rules to help people in a chat room, and help in general should always be encouraged. Note that there are different forms of help; simply giving someone an answer isn't usually the best form of help, but responding a call for help with a nudge toward a useful doc or a helpful tutorial will go a long way and should never be discouraged. Again, just because you hide behind averages as an excuse to not help someone doesn't mean you should pressure others into behaving the same way.

Comment: @TylerH "It's not against the rules" But it is discouraged. Maybe it *should* be against the rules. "always be encouraged" Always is always misused :P. "a nudge toward a useful doc" That's called a comment - no chat needed. "Just because I do X doesn't mean others must to X" Duh. But since I'm doing X and lots of people are doing X and X is the point of the site and not doing X is discouraged… maybe it's a good idea if everyone can just accept this is a site for "professional or enthusiast programers" - helping to the point of needing chat is *too much*.

Comment: @bjb568 If someone shows up in a chat room, you can't really comment, but you can respond to their message in chat. I'm referring to when people appear directly in chat or are in chat already and then have a question, rather than being directed there from a question.

Comment: @Tyler Why would a sub-20 user already be in a chat room?

Comment: @bjb568 I understand that 20-rep users are the topic of the question, but the above scenario already applies to 20+ rep users, and can apply to sub-20-rep users should this feature be approved.

Comment: @Tyler But how often are there 20-rep users who can actually make a room a better place? Versus how much harm it would do… "hey you is mean y other guy get chat halp"

Comment: @bjb568 I think your opinion of 20-rep users is incredibly jaded and inaccurate.

Comment: @bjb568 I should clarify. I think your opinion of 20-rep users *in chat rooms* is incredibly jaded and inaccurate. Also, FWIW, I can't see that link; I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @TylerH In chat rooms? How can I get an accurate idea of what they're like in chat when they aren't? Anyway, I know that <1k users are annoying enough.

Comment: @bjb568 Like I've already said, the points I've made apply to 20 rep users already and similarly low-repped question askers. I do suppose it could vary from room to room, but in the room I frequent, when someone comes in to ask a question, we typically do the best we can to give them the best kind of help.

Comment: @TylerH Which can get excessive, so a 20 rep requirement was put in place.

Comment: @bjb568 if you think it's excessive to help people when they ask then maybe helping people isn't the thing for you. Over time more people will come to StackOverflow and more people will get into programming, so it flows logically from that that more people will need help. There will always be people who need help. If you want to limit yourself to a few people helped that's fine, but don't place the limit on the rest of us.

Comment: @TylerH Asking and answering quality questions that the community can benefit from is fine. Encouraging bad questions by rewarding OP is destructive. Hand-holding != helping.

Comment: @Zero It gives the feeling "Yes! I'm being helped! I'll ask more crap questions!" instead of "This community seems to not welcome my questions as they are crap.". The second is the impression we want to give, since it decreases crap.

Comment: @bjb568 Having a low reputation does not mean that a user's questions are "crap". It just means they're new to the site. There's a difference.

Comment: @duskwuff There is a positive collation between <20 rep user and crap. In any case, we are already assuming the question is crap which is why the user needs hand holding.

Comment: I strongly agree with this proposition. I can see why this restriction is in place. Perhaps not allowing access until the account is at least one day old could work, as an alternative.

Comment: @Zero Something good is something that doesn't require hand holding. If a question is so bad that you have to go to chat to teach them how to use the site, a question ban is much more effective.

Comment: @bjb568 you know the chat system well enough to know that we (the JavaScript room) do not tolerate help vamps. Sending low users to chat is easily controllable, and revoking access is just as easy. Also, NEVER TRUST REPUATION. I've seen 1 rep users blow my answers out of the water, and I've seen 100k rep users post the worst answers I've ever seen. Rep doesn't determine the ability to ask a good question and give a good answer. There's a correlation, but it's not always true.

Comment: @RUJordan It may be easy, but why bother in the first place? Users under 20 rep who don't just post unhelpable crap is very rare. If they were any good they'd get their 2 upvotes pretty fast.

Comment: Suppose a new person comes to this site. They are new to programming, have actually read the rules, and realize the question they have is not up to par for main, and they aren't good enough at programming to answer any questions yet. Should they be punished by having no chat access to poke in?

Comment: "They are new to programming" Stop right there! This is for professionals and enthusiasts.

Comment: A programming noob can't be an enthusiast?

Comment: Not really, no. "can u recomnd jquery plugin thx"

Comment: You have clearly misread everything I posted. As many jquery plugin trolls as S/O has, I was referring to those who can actually ask a question. And yes, noobs can be enthusiasts. You don't have to be good to like something

Comment: "those who can actually ask a question" How often is that somebody below 20 rep? 200 rep even? While you don't have to be good to like something, every bobby tables on the street isn't a "programming enthusiast" just because they heard about "zeros and ones".

Comment: Beginners are some of the most enthusiastic programmers I've met.

Comment: @bjb568 I'm a football enthusiast yet miraculously, I'm not a professional player. HMMMMM.

Comment: @RUJordan At least you know what a football is. Most crap question askers (mostly low rep) probably don't know what a computer is.

Comment: And most terrible meta commenters make sweeping assumptions about others.

Comment: @SomeKittens Have you seen the home page? 90% of questions by <20 rep users can be flagged as VLQ.

Comment: ^ I REUQEST SOURCES GOOD SIR

Comment: @RUJordan http://i.stack.imgur.com/nDJKF.png

Comment: @bjb568 your argument boils down to "People aren't worth my time until they prove they are." I don't agree with that philosophy, but the fundamental problem with it in this instance is that this feature request is all about **allowing** new users to prove that they are. You should be supporting this wholeheartedly, if you sincerely think most new users "probably don't know what a computer is."

Comment: @Adam They don't need to prove to me by taking a stupid test, modifying the nonexistent test to work in chat isn't a good idea because the stupid test doesn't exist. Why would I test new users? The community does by grading their behavior thru voting. If they are genuinely good users, they don't need chat at all (but would get the privilege). If they're struggling with the site, chat almost always won't help them. Even if it did, helping them thru chat takes a lot of effort and doesn't scale. Helping them in general makes them feel welcome when that is not the impression that we want to give.

Comment: "Helping them in general makes them feel welcome when that is not the impression that we want to give." wait what? dude, what the hell? we are no longer supposed to make users feel welcomed?

Comment: No wonder you call everything "crap"

Comment: @rlemon Making people feel good for doing bad things is wrong. If they asked a bad question, helping them encourages more bad questions.

Comment: @bjb568 We're not making them feel good for doing bad things. Helping someone improve their question isn't _making them feel good about doing bad things_. The fact that they want to go to chat shows that they care about their question and more importantly the site, and maybe they'll stick around if they see people being helpful.

Comment: @justcool Helping somebody improve their question is helping them. That makes them feel good. For making a bad question. Going to chat is just another way to communicate attempted vamping.

Comment: @bjb568 I think helping somebody improve their question/answer is the point.

Comment: @justcool You can leave a comment. If you *really* need it, use meta.

Comment: Stop discriminating lower reps, and let them have a little chat with the experienced programmers. this would improve their skills
I am quite active in the Python chat, and I've learned ALOT from the chat, it's just unfair for new members, give them a chance:)

Comment: So...... is anything getting done about this then? Everyone seems to have been in favor of it?

Comment: Is it possible that they've implemented <20 rep access in auto-chatrooms? Reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381055/a-user-lost-the-username-in-the-chat-room. If that's the case it should be quite easy to nudge the company to enable the same feature for room owners...

Comment: Wow. I just tried to do the same thing (grant access to a "gallery" mode chatroom to a low reputation user, so that we could have a more effect conversation that in the comments on my answer), and was misled by the help text for "explicit write access" much like other folks have been for the past six (!!) years. Other than a +1 on this feature request, is there anything I can do to advocate for it? I see almost nothing but support for the idea here.

Comment: @larsks See this Meta.SE post: [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without)

Answer (score 77):

STRONGLY in favor of this feature request. I understand it's been said before that new users should stick to asking and answering questions to get a "feel" for the site as opposed to flooding chat with silly questions that cannot be fully answered there, but for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873297/while-loop-ignores-my-if-statement#comment34900258_22873297) is a specific incident where the user is trying to figure out how to better design their program, but doesn't have a question specific enough to get a good answer. I tried to engage them in chat, mistakenly believing that if I was the room owner and gave them explicit write privileges that it would override the "too low rep" restriction.

Not to mince words: **There was a user here that I was capable of helping, deserved help, and whom I wanted to help, and I was unable to because of a software restriction.** I have no problem with low rep users not being able to participate in public chat, but I have a BIG problem in an established user not being able to invite them to chat to more deeply discuss their problem.

Answer (score 43):

I favor this feature request.

There are many cases where a low-rep user shows willingness to learn something instead of saying "im a newbie, pls tell me how to do it". In many such cases, I want to be able to help the user, but can't because they don't have enough reputation to chat.

Discriminating users based on their reputation is not a good idea, at least when determining if they're eligible to join chat. A user's reputation being 1 doesn't mean they are dumb. Nor does it mean they're incapable of contributing to a productive discussion. Some of these new users are actually quite capable and might be experts at what they do — if you can get them to engage in a healthy conversion, it might encourage them to be an active contributor.

I'll admit to having upvoted one or two questions of the question-asker in order to get them into chat. With this feature, that won't be needed any more. It will also help reduce the clutter (read: noise, that adds nothing useful the post) in the comments under a question.

Answer (score 11):

I just came across this same issue. The odd thing is that the description of "write access" states:

> Even when this room is read-only or their *reputation is too low*, these users will be able to talk in this room. (emphasis mine)

I was trying to chat with a user whose rep is below the 20 threshold, so based on the description, giving them explicit write access should allow them to chat regardless of their rep, but instead I get an error message:

> Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk

That's completely counter-intuitive. If they have more than 20 rep, they don't need explicit write access. This feels like a bug to me.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I think it would be nice to just be able to trigger the "Let's continue this in chat" functionality, and then allow that to bypass the rep limit. Not sure if there should be a rep threshold for the helper.

I've had a couple of occasions where it appeared that the OP needed some minor but more conversational help, when their question had *potential*. I'd love it if the possibility were there to help them in that way. I probably wouldn't use it *often*, maybe once every (other) month, but it would be handy to help some of those new at SO get better.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big proponent of chat. I do support the intent of the request here because I feel that there's value in it as a concept. That said, I feel like the implementation requested here is too broad and might end up being riskier than it's worth.

Before I go into details on why, I'll say that, the answer here is "official" in that we're tagging this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). The biggest factor in that decline is that we're really not able to spend any time on Chat (Bonfire) right now and that, if we did, we'd likely want to do a more comprehensive overhaul of chat permissions and moderation. As such, the arguments below have less bearing on this status than the simple fact we have no current plans (that I'm aware of) to work on Chat.

#### Tying Chat permissions to RO status

This request is really highly upvoted for understandable reasons - there's a big need, and there has been for a while, for us to rethink the restrictions on who can access Chat. I'd love for more people to be able to use it because I sincerely feel that it's one of the best places on our site for real-time help improving posts (and asking more subjective questions) while also being really useful for async conversations.

On top of that, I'm a Community Manager who's focused on engagement and Chat is one of the most powerful tools we have to increase engagement and sense of community because it's pretty much the only place on the site you can just hang out and let your personality show.

In the case of big rooms where there's trusted ROs who keep things in line, this request is understandable and reasonable. The major concern that we have from a trust and safety perspective is that, while tying this to RO status (rather than pure reputation as suggested in [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260919/4548692)) will protect these very active rooms from random people being let in by unaffiliated 500 reputation users, it doesn't prevent an issue that's a bit more concerning to us.

Right now, anyone with at least 100 reputation can create a room and become an RO. If this request was granted, they could then give permission to anyone they wish to join them in their room. That opens up a huge space for potential risk for unmoderated chat between users who haven't really shown they are trustworthy. Additionally, the system will assign RO status to the most chatty user in rooms that don't have ROs.

While it may seem low risk and low impact - sure, they're only talking in their little corner of Chat - but there's a higher risk that their discussions might be less appropriate than currently exists. Maybe my concern and hand-wringing will come to naught but I'd much rather think about wholistic improvements to chat moderation instead of trusting anyone who hits 100 rep with granting access to anyone they wish.

You might ask... "How is this hugely different amounts of risk than a room full of 20 reputation users?" and that's a valid question... to me it just feels more scary. In the case of a bunch of 20 rep users, they all had to do something to earn that rep. If one 100 rep user can create a chat room for a dozen 1 rep users to access chat... that feels a lot simpler to achieve.

#### Improving Chat moderation

##### Huge caveat here - this section details my personal feelings about how I imagine chat could be better moderated. It doesn't indicate any support from the company or any plans in this direction.

The first big thing here is that the fact that only site mods can be Chat mods is... a problem. Site mods might not be frequent Chat users and Chat just feels like it's more immediate and needs more urgent handling of problematic content.

[A couple of years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357905/new-chat-moderation-tools-for-the-teachers-lounge) we created a new concept for Chat - the Room Moderator. This is separate from Site mods, ROs or even overall Chat moderators. These are people who have, essentially, the same abilities as Site mods but scoped to a specific room. They have more control over room access, flag handling, message deletion, etc... but only in that room. These people are appointed by Chat moderators.

The important thing is, unlike ROs, not all Chat rooms *need* Room Moderators, only the more active ones that are often dealing with more people and differing personalities. This request feels like something that would come into play with that role or the creation of Chat Mods that are independent from being site moderators... something that is a bit more restrictive than simply "all people with RO status".

All of this falls into the realm of something I know many of you have heard me say before - **we need to reconsider whether relying on reputation points to determine whether someone is allowed to do something is the best solution**. We need to, instead, think about how they can show they have the necessary skills or trainings to earn that ability and then make sure they use it effectively. I'm really looking forward to how we can improve our privilege systems, even outside chat.

Comment: I like this answer, largely agree with the musings, and, above all, agree with the decision to decline the feature request. However, I don't know whether to upvote or downvote it, because the answer isn't definitely rejecting the feature request, which is what I'd prefer to see happen. Chat is a privilege, which should be earned, and the bar is already extremely low. Reputation is not a great metric for many things, but it is still a useful metric for one's *basic familiarity* with the site, and 20 rep is earned by posting a single good question or answer or two OK questions and/or answers.

Comment: I appreciate that there is at least an official response on the matter, and am not surprised that chat features are still being deprioritized. I think that this restriction comes at a heavy cost in terms of site usability: **many** new questions from 1-rep users end up with **very long** comment threads while people try to figure out *whether or not there is* a site-appropriate question underneath. Meanwhile, almost new person who comes to Stack Overflow seems to *want and expect* a discussion forum, no matter how much we tell them it's not.

Comment: (con't.) Better IMO to let them start out in a room by themselves, where they don't interfere with anyone: either in the big chats like the main Python room, or in the questions feed (until the question is at least sort-of refined).

Comment: I'd forgotten I'd posted this 8+ years ago lol. I don't completely agree with the reasoning but understand it. Umm... pending an overhaul to the chat system and privileges could we at least do something about the "misleading" text that Chris put in an answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334445 ?

Answer (score 4):

From [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335486/289691) to [Moderator moves comments to chat - can low-rep user participate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335485/289691)

> Upon further investigation in a chat room in which this recently occurred, it appears that all existing participants ARE automatically added to the "Explicit write access" list for the room at the time it is created, even those with <20 rep.
>
> Thanks to Zoe for pointing out where to look for this information.
>
> This does not apply to normal users using the option to "continue" a discussion in chat - it only applies to moderator comment moves.

What about if this "mod privilege" is extended to gold tag-badge holders or included as part of the privileges for rep >10k?

Related [Meta SE] [Add new / low rep users to chat rooms created "continue discussion in chat" by gold tag badge holders (or alike privilege based)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383061/289691)

Answer (score -10):

I agree as well. But it does not need to be room owner. Any person with say 500 rep shall be able to invite low rep user to chat. I have seen today some newbie but his post was very low quality so it was downvoted and closed immediately. Answearing such broad question did not make sense. But sharing some thoughts in chat would do.

Comment: I think 500 rep is way too low. I wouldn't trust a 500 rep user with such a privilege. I would be more trusting of a user with at least 2000 or 3000 rep.

Comment: I forgot to mention it shall be onetime privilege. So there is no hurt. If the bar is high this feature is less useful.

Comment: If it was 500 rep, i'd expect the person who invited said person to be kicked in the event the person they invite gets kicked with a matching duration.