# As the owner of a room, I am unable to grant explicit write access

Tags: support, chat

I'm confused by the privileges of a room owner.

As a room owner, I can access the rooms `access` settings.

Among those settings, I find:

> Explicit write access
>
> Even when this room is read-only or their reputation is too low, these users will be able to talk in this room.

I notice **even when ... their reputation points are too low**. So I try to add a user to the chat, only to be greeted by a "Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk" error message.

I also find the feature request *[Room owners should be allowed to accept <20 rep users to talk in a room](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room)* which seems to suggest the feature I'm viewing does not exist.

Can I, as a room owner, invite users with too low reputation points into a specific chat room?

Comment: As a sidenote, is it really _that_ hard to get 20 rep? 10 approved edits, 4 question upvotes, 2 answer upvotes or any combination.

Comment: @Carrie A lot of the low-hanging fruit in the more-popular languages has gone, so it is a bit harder to get 20 rep than it used to be. It possibly *appears* difficult enough to discourage new starters unless they know they've got some specific knowledge to offer. It's a more interesting question than it might appear at first glance, as the site continues to mature.

Comment: @Frosty840 I would fully agree, if <2k users didn't get rep for edits. Even with nothing to contribute knowledge-wise, you can edit.

Comment: @Carrie Oh, it's not about the difficulty –I completely agree with you on that side–, it's about the *perception* of difficulty. If a user happens to be familiar with a rep=votes site such as reddit, other methods of gaining rep aren't so obvious, because there's an expectation that they don't exist, and so users might not think to look for alternative rep-gaining methods.

Comment: @CarrieKendall it may be easy to get those votes, but the time spent jumping through those hoops (perhaps 2 hours) can be considered non-trivial. You're in the top 3% for the quarter, for example, and you're probably earning 20 reputation a day for upvotes/answers. Gone are the days where people get a +1 for trying.

Comment: @Compass I take your point, but if you want the privileges you have to earn them. This is a very low bar. It takes me about 15-20 minutes to do 10 thorough edits.

Comment: @CarrieKendall But we don't need them approved like new users do.

Comment: @Compass that doesn't change the amount of time it _takes to do the edit_. I don't understand what you're getting at there. Also, the majority of my sitting answers that I collect rep on are new. Of my 48 answers around 20 of them were posted this year.

Comment: @CarrieKendall We are not supposed to use extended discussions in comments; we are encouraged to move discussions to chat. The disconnect is there, because, while users are allowed to comment on their own questions without reputation, they are unable to participate in chat for issues regarding their own questions.

Comment: @CarrieKendall As a low-rep user that has to suggest edits, let me give you a bit more insight on it: While taking the time to do the edit is very low, low-rep editors have to wait for the edits to be approved, or rejected. We also have to make sure the edit is significant enough that it will be accepted by the system, then not likely rejected by the reviewers. 2k editors don't have to worry as much about this, so it's a lot easier to edit and go. Even when a low-rep user like myself makes a good edit, it can take time to get the rep for it. It's easy, but time consuming.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me for disagreeing. These points sound whiny. If you want the privilege of using chat then prove you're a human, contribute to the community and gain the privilege. It is really that simple.

Comment: You're forgetting the point, not everyone is here for the imaginary-Internet-points. Some (a lot of) people just create a account to ask for help in a particular problem, and don't stay here for long. Editing should be voluntary, after all it's time-consuming and sounds just like housekeeping. Imagine you opening your recently-created Google account to do something important, only to find that you can't use Hangouts until you've fixed spelling errors on 4 different emails by random people. It's ridiculous to be required to contribute to the site when you barely have a idea of its scale.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see you'd mentioned Jon's request in your body. In that case, it's not been implemented yet :(