# Explicit write access in chat

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, chat

I know this has been [requested in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room) but I'm very confused as to whether it has been implemented or not:

> **Explicit write access add a user**
>
> Even when this room is read-only or their reputation is too low, these users will be able to talk in this room.

This very clearly states "or their reputation is too low" so therefore:

**a) This has been implemented, and the fact that it doesn't work for <20 rep users is a bug.**

or

**b) This hasn't been implemented, in which case that wording needs to be changed because it simply isn't true.**

---

I'm also aware that the *right to do this as a room owner* [has been asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280734/as-the-owner-of-a-room-i-am-unable-to-grant-explicit-write-access) however that just points back to the first post I linked. Nothing actually states what room owners are supposed to be able to do here....

Comment: For the rep limit I think it only works for people who were able to chat before.  Then lost that due to voting/suspension.

Comment: @NathanOliver surely in that scenario they should also lose the ability as they would with any other perk? Seems to be a bit of an exception

Comment: In any case - if that's true I think it should be made clear in the explanatory text on that page.

Comment: One of the silly consequences of this is that if you want a bot that can take action in the room, you need to get 20 rep as the bot to chat, rather than just adding it to the write list.  Not that that's particularly hard to do.

Comment: @davidism tell that to [Chatty McChatface](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6365783/chatty-mcchatface)

Comment: @NathanOliver It seems unlikely that you could allow a user to chat when they're suspended. Users who fell below 20 points, that I could imagine.