# Invite a user to chat from chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

Inviting a user to a chat room seems a bit cumbersome right now when the room already exists. I have to go search for the user's profile page, then click through a drop-down of the chats I'm in and choose to invite them. It seems like something I should be able to do from within the chat room. What would be be really nice is something like this:

1. From the chat room, under the list of users add a link to "Invite a user to chat".
2. Show a modal with a text box for typing in the user name.
3. As you type, update a list of users matching that name under the text box.
4. Select one (or multiple?) users, and click an "Invite" button.

Comment: This feature request might be the same thing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room?rq=1

Comment: How would you know which user to invite from the chat room if you hadn't already located them from SO main?

Comment: Maybe I know a user by name who could help with a question. Or, like my situation yesterday, a user could have been in that chat room and asked a question then left before someone could answer. I answered the question and invited him back.