# Is it acceptable if I create a chat room linked to a specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, chat

Before opening a new chat room on a specific topic, I would like to have some feedback on the arguments that I can see for and against it.

**Context**

1. In the tag [chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef) there are a lot of "How to start"/"Beginner" questions which tend to be off-topic for Stack Overflow (because they are not code-related and usually quite opiniated). The comments on these questions and answers are often quite chatty, even when they're on-topic.
2. There are already chat rooms existing on IRC for this subject.

**My thought**

A chat room may help driving users to correct resources (tutorials/documentation) and narrowing their problem before opening a new question.

**My questions**

Should I open a chat room on this subject to allow a chat with those users, even on off-topic subjects?

Or should I:

- keep commenting on questions and provide documentation links?
- give a link to IRC where the questions are really broad and not adapted to SO?
- only redirect them to the tag information which already list those resources?

Comment: Note that users need 20 rep points to use chat.

Comment: [Relevant feature request about inviting users below the 20-rep limit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257949/1204258)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fire up the chat room! :)

There is really no downside to adding an on topic chat room, even if at times it can become off topic. Many of the popular rooms contain off topic chat, but *rarely* (not really, it is pretty common). Feel free to field any sort of question that you are comfortable with there.

The only issue you will have is keeping the room active and not being too wild. While chat is somewhat unregulated, egregious behavior will be noticed and could result in suspension from chat or the main site depending on the situation. This is very uncommon.

If the room lacks activity it will eventually be frozen and removed (soft-deleted). This is probably "worst-case scenario" for any user created chat room.

All in all, there is no harm to creating the room. Just keep in mind that it may just be an echo chamber if the tag is not very active or the scope is too narrow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for the late acceptation. I'll open it and see if it can help improve the tag.