# 1 rep user requesting access to a gallery chatroom

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I'm a RO of a gallery chatroom, and for whatever reason a 1 rep user requested access to the room. For those who don't see why that is a problem, the request itself isn't. Except you need 20 rep to chat and there is [still no way to allow < 20 rep users to chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room).

I clicked on the dialog when it popped up, but no users were shown on the list of people who have requested access.

I checked again a while later and the user was on the list (wasn't there when the request dropped in, no new requests were made as that would show a new dialog). For testing I tried granting write access, but since the user < 20 rep the "Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk" warning shows up.

I checked it instantly when it came in, there was no visible users requesting more access at the time and looking in chat the user had 1 rep when requesting. (even deleted posts carry impact, the account has been seen by no one, 0 people impacted, no votes, no flags and no edits. The user in question has had to have 1 rep when requesting as well)

The last part is relevant because of [this post on SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226322/why-can-some-users-below-20-reputation-send-requests-for-write-access-in-chat-ro). There is no visible evidence there has been any rep there in the first place. And if there was, the profile picture would have been visible. Meaning the problem isn't related to the user losing rep, the account isn't banned (on SO or in chat) meaning the user has to have had < 20 rep when requesting. Which is why I tagged this with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug).

How can a < 20 rep user request access to a gallery room when they shouldn't be able to request access in the first place, and they can't be granted write access?

**EDIT:**

Another 1 rep user just (as of this edit) requested access to the room. I still can't grant write access and the user didn't have 20 or more rep when requesting. It is a different user than the first one who requested access.

Comment: I wonder if someone introduced a bug when they did the mentorship thing. As I recall, it involved sending new users (1 rep, probably) to specific chatrooms, so somebody could conceivably have messed with that code.

Comment: I think I found where these is coming from. The good news is it’s probably just UI leaking and not users doing anything nefarious. Handing it off since I don’t have a working chat instance though.

Comment: @BrianNickel heard anything more about it?

Comment: @BrianNickel 6 weeks later, any updates?

Comment: yo, it would be cool to get an update on this.

Comment: @BrianNickel By now the Android room even has a bot so they don't have to deal with those requests anymore. Is there any update on this? Is it even investigated or deemed "not high priority"? I know you handed it off but you are the only one with a diamond around ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fixed, based on the assumption that people were requesting access via incorrect logic on the mobile view.  The logic and messaging for both the new and the old mobile views has been updated to match desktop.

If the problem isn't resolved, I'll go ahead and tweak the backend code.  There currently isn't any error handling code on that button and I don't want to break any esoteric access granting routes, so I'm gonna leave well enough alone.