# Stack Overflow should not invite you to move a discussion to chat when one of the participants doesn't have enough reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

This is basically the same as [Chat with a new user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255866/chat-with-a-new-user), but I'm upgrading this to a bug report, because it is a confounded nuisance and makes it hard to help the people who need it most.

Ideally:

- If neither user has chat privileges, then the chat offer should not appear.
- If one user has chat privileges and the other does not, then the 'senior' person should be able to invite the other to chat.
- If both users have chat privileges, then the current system is fine.

Failing that:

- If one of the users does not have chat privileges, then the chat offer should not appear at all. It is pointless offering an option and then saying "Oh, sorry — just joking!".

I'd be OK with a requirement that you must have a somewhat higher reputation (maybe 100 which is the level at which you can create a new chat room) to be able to invite an under-privileged user to join you in chat. But if you want to avoid protracted discussions, it is often the low-level users who need the chat privilege.

Exemplar: [Translating an integer and a character into several forms in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26667475/15168).

Comment: Is this essentially the same as [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep) over on MSE?

Comment: It's the same problem; it's the 'New suggestion' at the end of that question revived as a bug report, instead of a feature request.  It's not good UI that you get asked to do something, do it, and then get told "you can't".  That is bad — very bad!  As in "it is a bug".

Comment: I think one of the reasons for not changing it is that reputation might change in the interim, for the good or for worse. So, in principle the data is always stale, for everyone, until they open chat (or try to).

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well, another option might be to exceptionally allow all users (regardless of their reputation) to move to the chat when invited by the system. This way there is no longer a moving target :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. This is the solution I'd prefer. Given that AFAIK chatting is something that requires two-party consent - one person can't spam the chat until the chat message shows up, then spam them with messages - I can't really see the use in having chat be reputation-limited. The kinds of people who want you to be constantly on the hook to give you help are the kind of people who are going to spam you some way no matter what.

Comment: I block that message with a userscript.

Comment: **"Oh, sorry — just joking!"** - this happens when trying to close off topic questions having bounty as well... Why show the close button at all if it can't be closed..!

Comment: @TJ: To taunt you, what else?

Comment: Also closely related to [Advice to "automatically move this discussion to chat" even when the other commenter has < 20 rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261711/advice-to-automatically-move-this-discussion-to-chat-even-when-the-other-comme).  Again, the difference is this is a bug report; that is a feature request.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The next build will only show the advice to move the discussion to chat if both users have the permission.  The case of a high rep user inviting a low rep user to chat will need to be looked at a bit more.

Comment: OK — thank you.  That's a step in the right general direction.  Please do consider the 'do you want to invite this (low reputation) user to join a chat' option.

Comment: We should IMO be able to chat! This 20rep make sense for public chat, not for a room about a question.

Comment: The lack of options to move a (low rep user) to a chat by a (high rep user) is a problem more often than not. The `senior` user should be able to do that. Was this discussed (and ditched?) elsewhere?