# Proposal: Possibillity to start chat with low rep users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Quite often I find that new users of SO also are new as programmers. Which could lead to a bunch of trivial problems easily solved in chat. But since you can't chat with low rep users these kind of questions tend to end up in a very long comment section.

Why isn't it possible for highrep users to initiate a chat with these users? That would certainly help them and at the same time keep comments to a minimum!

Comment: I see potential with this idea, but you'd need to add more specifics . Also, it may help to show examples of how this would work.   Another point - why limit the insta-chat to low-rep users? Why not everyone ?

Comment: How Would this be  different from current chat?

Comment: @Coffee 20 rep is currently required for any chat. Note, this has a duplicate somewhere, currently trying to find...

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat

Comment: And apparently we can already do it, as room-owners have write access privileges. See the last answer on the duplicate

Comment: Philip , do you want a more lightweight version of chat? Maybe something quick & dirty? I guess that may be interesting .. but currently as Bradley says - we do have chat

Comment: That would be one solution. Right now I often find that lowrep users need aditional guidence that i would gladly give but it's not possible in the standard SO format. Any solution that would give me the possibility to "talk" with that person would be great. A Stripped version of chat would most certinly suffice.

Comment: No not that easy and i belive that if you use a public chat room. newcomers would be easily distracted by others posting in the same room. (But i could be wrong)

Comment: @PhilipG In created rooms, it almost always just you and the other guy. Plus, higher rep users can create gallery rooms to *really* lock it down.'

Comment: I see your point, but it clearly says `IMPORTANT: please check for an existing similar room before creating a new room; duplicate rooms (without good cause) will be closed.` this gives me the impression that I shouldn't create these "narrow" rooms. But i could be wrong.

Comment: The system *already* creates these narrow rooms with the "move comment discussions to chat" features. I've created them for one-on-one chats and never had a problem. I'm sure they got closed when we both left, but thats fine, it was *supposed* to be short-term.

Comment: I like the idea. The core issue is to make the cost of opening up a chat as small as possible.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have been in a similar situation with a low-rep user who _was_ friendly. It indeed took me 5 minutes to set up a chat room and figure out how to grant write access, and after all that I discovered by myself that I still can't grant write to low-rep users. I ended up upvoting the new user's post to push him over the minimum, an upvote I would not otherwise have given. This is a problem; _Please_ allow us to trigger a move-discussion-to-chatroom before the system volunteers it itself, and allow us to grant write access to the low-rep user concerned (or do so automatically).

Comment: I didn't know there is a chat in SO until I saw this, and even after reading this, I find it hard to look for the chat room :)

Comment: @Wayne www.chat.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update**: Apparently the text on the owners page lies, and this doesn't work yet :(

The solution described on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189276/274565) is unfortunately not feasible yet.If it was, to chat with a low-rep user, you need to:

1. Have that user visit chat.stackoverflow.com
2. Create a new room
3. Give the user write access to that room (via the "info" link)
4. Share the link of that room with the user (via comments)
5. ???
6. Profit.

Certainly it would be nice if this were streamlined a bit, but it should work.

Comment: Doesn't this approach result in VERY many rooms without a good purpose?

Comment: @PhilipG The system already accounts for this possibility for the "Move comment discussion to chat" feature. I've created rooms before that kicked in when it was obvious that chat was needed and have had no problems. Of course, the rooms can go away after you both leave (eventually), but thats not really an issue. For example, there are 2 "dead" rooms currently from my discussions, but I've had *way* more than that. I'm sure the system will clean them up soon.

Comment: I'm not 100% this *is* implemented - that post is from 2013... there's two related posts on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275771/stack-overflow-should-not-invite-you-to-move-a-discussion-to-chat-when-one-of-th which are related to the 20 rep requirement

Comment: @JonClements Granted, I have not tried this yet. The "write access" box *does* indicate that it grants access regardless of reputation though. Know any low-rep users who want to be a guinea pig?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET sadly it doesn't work - else I wouldn't have had to write a MSO post regarding it in June :( It appears the vast majority of commenters (which also aired pretty much the same points the OP did here) and answerers were for the idea of it (including a couple of mods) - but as far as I'm aware - there's been no changes

Comment: @JonClements They really need to change that text then :(. I still want to find a low-rep user and try this... If only I could log in as two users on the same computer.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: First, make a dry-run using just any arbitrary 1-rep-user. I think your attempt will be blocked, as you aren't a mod. If not, enlist someone for real.

Comment: Yeah, this still only works for moderators.

Answer (score 33):

[contributor wastes 5 minutes setting up chatroom]..

user99999: 'What did I do wrong?'

contributor101: 'Well, if you go back to the help and take the tour, you will see that some little effort is very useful to enable us to assist you better.  Your requirement dump is not useful to present and future visitors to SO and your code snippet won't even compile.  Please include all inputs, outputs, error messages and log entries.  If you have done any debugging, please let us know what you found out since that will save us all time.  If you help us a bit, maybe we can help you a lot'

user99999: 'Ok, I get it.  Now, are you going to do my homework?  If not piss off and stop wasting my time'

Am I being too cynical?  I somehow doubt it.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with this - Too many new users are self-centered on original entering of the site, which is to solve their specific problem - they often have no incentive to improve the site on a low rep and contribution status, which is kind of why I appreciate having a rep limit for users who are able to chat, which filters out a severe amount of 'users who I do not believe should deserve help from mediums of this particular chat', as contrary to mediums like IRC.

Comment: At least you painted the contributor101 as too naive. Just write a short comment with the most pressing issue and wait for a decent replay. If none comes, close chat. This simple rule will almost 100% sure avoid any waste of time.

Comment: Presumably contributer101 would be intelligent enough to know if the individual is worth chatting with before wasting the five minutes. If not, well, I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @Unihedro just because a *lot* of users are like that, doesn't mean they're *all* like that. And it's impossible to predict at the outset of the conversation. Just streamline the process so that inviting them to chat doesn't waste anybody's time.

Comment: At the point where you get that response, you leave the chat room and downvote the question, leaving a comment and a reference to the chat room where the evidence of bone-headed behaviour is on display.  I've not experienced that level of contemptuousness...I can't say it doesn't happen, but it hasn't happened to me yet.

Comment: @MarkRansom: "a lot" is an understatement. I used "too many" and mean _too many_. If new user X is of interest to help both the site and their problem, they would stick and live through the "new user restrictions removal" stage.

Comment: You can often see in the way the question is asked if OP while being a new programmer and so asking basic questions without knowing how to find the answer *does its best* or not and deserves help. We all were once newbees, and provided OP is correct and tries to understand, I'm often ready to spend time to show him (or her) where the problem is and how to avoid it (of course when I have the time to spend ...). But without chat it often requires many comments and edits :-(

Comment: Just a small fraction of users would overextend and ask too much. Besides it is quite easy to explain that they are asking too much. If they still dont understand, it wouldnt matter since it's as easy to stop the conversation.