# Do we need a "too many comments" auto flag that flags up potential arguments or some users "ganging up" on posters?

Tags: discussion, comments, auto-flags

Currently the "too many comments" flag is raised when there are more than 25 comments posted in the past 3 days. This means that it fires - especially on controversial meta posts - when there is nothing that the moderators can, or need, to do. It also potentially fires too late when the argument has finished but the evidence is still laid out for all to see.

Would a better flag be one that gets raised when 80%<sup>*</sup> of the comments have been contributed by the same < 4<sup>*</sup> users in less than a day<sup>*</sup>? This would alert us to potential comment arguments and hopefully allow us to step in and defuse the situation (or at least remove the comments).

I realise that there's already the "auto-comment" directing users to chat when they've exceeded a certain number of comments, but this flag would for cases where they ignore that or other users have joined in.

* figures plucked out of nowhere and subject to change when more evidence is presented.

Comment: Y'all's is 25? Interesting. I think it's 20 most places. This would have to have some sort of minimum number of comments, else you'd immediately have it flag every post ;) I guess you could set it at 10 minimum? My concern would be a ton of false positives. If the OP and someone else are having an honest back and forth in improving/clarifying the question, that would trigger this along with actual arguments. I'm guessing that if there's one thing SO mods don't need, it's a bunch of fp auto flags.

Comment: @Catija That's a good point. I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be better if we could:

1. Choose to take a conversation to chat when it seems clear that it's going in that direction. As it stands, we have to wait for the box to show up to do that, even if we can tell that this will not be a short conversation.
2. *Force* people to go to chat past a certain point. As in, when the box says that they should take things to chat, don't give them the option not to. They would not allowed to post comments on that question/answer anymore (maybe for a period of time). Maybe even do it by turning their "comments" instantly into chat posts.

Comment: What's the current state of play on [Stack Overflow should not invite you to move a discussion to chat when one of the participants doesn't have enough reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275771)?  I've not been bugged by it for a while (maybe 3 years now), but the 'force to chat' won't work well if any of the users are low rep users unless the 'force to chat' gives them the necessary privilege for this chat.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, we could just allow lower-rep users to enter those temporary chatrooms. They're a vastly different experience from regular chatrooms.

Comment: It's just a factor to consider.  I don't think there can be more than a couple of low rep users involved in any single extended conversation — because low rep users who can't chat can only add comments to their own questions or answers (is that correct?).  If there are 3 low rep answerers all in discussions about a low rep user's question, then … Ugh!   But the issue will need to be handled, and on the whole I'd be in favour of granting participants with too low a rep temporary access to the temporary chat room.

Comment: I am all for **1** and often miss this feature, but for **2**, I have some concerns: Comments allow for a special rhythm in the conversation and is more a *public* thing, you can leave it and hope someone else will take the next steps. My experience with chats is that it is more time draining. I feel I have to always answer in the minute, if I don't, the other participant leaves, or I forget about it and since it's harder to keep track of this chat-room, I simply never come back.

Comment: Also, forbidding to post new comments should only be done if previous comments have not been cleaned up. One should be able to post a summary comment of the long discussion, which might add something useful to the post.

Comment: Moving to chat only works if people are in the same "time zone" and are interacting on the site at the same time. In my experience (for the tags I work in) that's only occasionally the case. And then there are the cases where people with too little knowledge are chiming in suggesting all kinds of things... Forcing chat would not be a good idea. Being able to *choose* to move to chat could be a good idea. Then I'd say after a certain reputation, perhaps even tag-specific.

Comment: @CindyMeister: But things only ever really enter that point where the "go to chat" message comes up when you have two people there, at the same time, going back and forth. If you're dumping messages 12 hours apart, you almost never get that.

Comment: I have encountered it, but seldom and there've been LOTS of comments (and lots of people putting their oars in the water) :-)