# Stack Overflow inviting users to move a discussion to chat when one of the participants doesn't have enough reputation

Tags: bug, chat, privileges, user-experience, error-message

In this related question:

[Stack Overflow should not invite you to move a discussion to chat when one of the participants doesn't have enough reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275771/stack-overflow-should-not-invite-you-to-move-a-discussion-to-chat-when-one-of-th)

The accepted answer (Feb 9 '15) states that:

> The next build will only show the advice to move the discussion to
> chat if both users have the permission. The case of a high rep user
> inviting a low rep user to chat will need to be looked at a bit more.

It is furthermore marked as [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Yesterday, and today, I have been greeted with:

[image]

on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66179213/rselenium-scraping-table/66185407?noredirect=1#comment117068198_66185407).

So, is the bug back and is it being dealt with?

Clearly, IMO, the check for whether to show this move message should occur after first checking both parties can make use of the chat feature.

I did check to see if this has been recently reported so apologies if I missed it.

Comment: Huh, is that pop up new? I don't remember seeing it before, if so, I prefer being given the option and told it's not allowed than not have the option at all

Comment: @Nick If you mean the red pop-up with unaliased id - I don't remember seeing it before.

Comment: I do, I'm assuming they've replaced the logic for deciding on whether or not to show the invitation to move the discussion to chat with the red pop-up. That's a change I'm happy with :p

Comment: @Nick I don't get it  (what I am seeing) as  1) these are often precisely the people needing to chat 2) how would that red box text work in isolation? My brain is a little mashed from work so .... ;-)

Comment: 1) Yep, and they still can't chat, nothing's changed on that front. 2) Offering to move chat and then not letting you is functionally identical to not offering at all. The advantage of the red box instead of not showing the offer is consistency of UI

Comment: As of 02/03/2021, on a different question, I sometimes also now get "null" appear in the little red pop-up box after asking me to move the convo to chat for a user with less than 20 rep.