# How to create a temporary chat room and how to delete it when done

Tags: support, feature-request, chat

So I have been in a couple of questions with SO users who keep further comments for clarification, etc. I have even had SO suggest to me to shift to a chat room. Rather than push more comments onto the thread to try to trigger this feature, I went and tried to create such a short-lived room.

```
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92425/questiononplot
```

This seems to be more long-lived than I intended.

1. What should I have done instead?
2. How do I delete said chatroom?
3. What do I do to support said user, who has insufficient rep to get into said chatroom anyway?

I think that this should also be a feature request, where we can move a long-winding thread to chat, especially for low-rep users who are the very ones who will most likely fall into my use-case of needing lots of prompting to reach a clarified state or requirements. And I would like this to be a temporary room because it is solely intended to move the noise out of band and keep the signal ratio high.

Comment: AFAIK You can't delete chatrooms, but after a period of inactivity it will age out and delete itself.

Comment: [I agree with the feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255828/1380752) but don't hold your breath

Comment: +1, but doesn't "explicit write access" take care of one of these points? Description: 
"Even when this room is read-only or their reputation is too low, these users will be able to talk in this room. "